# Rolling d20, d12, d10, d8, d6 in a row, what's the probability of a 1 on at least one of the rolls?

Tags: probability

So I roll a d20, d12, d10, d8, d6, one at a time, in a row. What are the chances of at least one roll to be a 1? And how do you calculate it?

Comment: By "either roll" do you mean *at least one of the rolls*?

Comment: Yes, at least one, I'll edit for clarification.

Comment: Any particular reason the d4 was omitted?

Comment: It's a specific scenario for D&D, one in which I needed 5 die. I might consider using a d4 and removing the d20 tho.

Comment: That (replacing d20 with d4) would give a probability nearer to 55% rather than 43%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is as follows: You work out the probability of the complementary event ("none of the rolls are 1").

You then use the multiplicative rule for independent events (die rolls are normally treated as independent, which is typically a pretty reasonable assumption).

So

P(none of the rolls are a 1) = P(d6 is not a 1) x P(d8 is not a 1) x ... x P(d20 is not a 1)

= 5/6 x 7/8 x 9/10 x 11/12 x 19/20

and so P(at least one of the rolls is a 1) = 1 - 5/6 x 7/8 x 9/10 x 11/12 x 19/20

This is about 42.85%

Comment: It's the same as doing P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B), two at a time. Thank you! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: It's really like doing P(A or B) = 1-P(not-{A or B}) = 1-P(not-A and not-B) = 1-P(not-A) x P(not-B) ... but with more than two events. [You could use the generalization of the approach mentioned in your comment (i.e. the principle of inclusion-exclusion) but it would be more involved.]